# Yii2: How to disable radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, radiobuttonlist

```
<?php  echo $form->field($model, 'status')->radioButtonGroup($model->getStatusList(), ['disabledItems'=>['APPROVED','DIGITAL','CDP']], 
    [
    'class' => 'btn-group-sm',
    'itemOptions' => ['labelOptions' => ['class' => 'btn btn-warning']]
    ]); 
    ?>
```

[image]

I want to disable all previous radio buttons from currently checked.
As I showed in image status 'APPROVED','DIGITAL','CDP' are disabled because status print is selected. I have put these three status in disabled function but how to achieve this using jQuery.

PS- Using Yii2

HTML Code-

```
<div class="form-group field-status-status required">
    <label class="control-label" for="status-status">Status</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="Status[status]" value="">
    <div id="status-status" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default disabled">
            <input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="APPROVED" disabled> Approved</label>
        <label class="btn btn-default disabled">
            <input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="DIGITAL" disabled> Digital</label>
        <label class="btn btn-default disabled">
            <input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="CDP" disabled> CDP</label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="PRINT"> Print</label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="OTHERPROCESS"> OtherProcess</label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="PACKING"> Packing</label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="DISPATCH"> Dispatch</label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `prop` to disable radio buttons.

```
$(':radio:checked').closest('label').prevAll('label :radio').prop('disabled', true);
```

Demo:

```js
$(':radio').on('change', function() {
  $(':radio:checked').closest('label').prevAll('label').addClass('disabled').children(':radio').prop('disabled', true);
}).trigger('change');
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group field-status-status required">
  <label class="control-label" for="status-status">Status</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="Status[status]" value="">
  <div id="status-status" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="APPROVED">Approved</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="DIGITAL">Digital</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="CDP" checked>CDP</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="PRINT">Print</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="OTHERPROCESS">OtherProcess</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="PACKING">Packing</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="DISPATCH">Dispatch</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you help me with full script, actually this page is for status update.
once the one status is selected user should not select previous status.
like I show in image if 'Print' is selected previous 3 status should automatically disable.

Comment: can it worked if value radio button is pre-selected ?

Comment: not getting expected output.. :( what is console log what value should i put instead of fdsafdsa ?

Comment: may be because of this console log? value should be change on place of fdsafdsa

Comment: ` <?php
$script = <<< JS



$(':radio').on('change', function() 
{
  console.log('fdsafdsa');
  $(':radio:checked').closest('label').prevAll('label').children(':radio').prop('disabled', true);
});


JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?> `

This what I'm putting at the end of the form

Comment: mate its working awesome functionally but on page the disabled buttons are still clickable its not look like disable button e.g grey..how can i make look like grey?

Comment: @Saurabh Add class of `disabled` to the `labels`